# Engagement Rate Filter is not returning any data

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

In GA4, when I filter my results with the Engagement Rate > XX, it returns no results. The case is that, on average, the engagement rate without any filtering is over the XX number I put. I post the image below as proof. When I remove the filter it returns results as expected. Any suggestions?

[image]